# Get one user with a query in graphql

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, typeorm

I have been trying to create create a query in grapqhl in express to get just one user
but is not working, it gives me all the users everytime

this is my query, I am using typeorm as ORM

```
import { GraphQLList, GraphQLID } from 'graphql';
import { UserType } from '../TypeDefs/User';
import { Users } from '../../Entities/Users';

export const GET_ALL_USERS = {
    type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
    resolve() {
        return Users.find();
    },
};

export const GET_USER = {
    type: GraphQLList(UserType),
    args: {
        userId: { type: GraphQLID },
    },
    async resolve(userId: any) {
        // const { userId } = args;
        const user = await Users.find({
            where: {
                userId: userId,
            },
        });

        return user;
    },

};
```

and this is the output in the Graphiql:

```
query{
  getUser(userId:"2"){
    name
    email
    userId
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUser": [
      {
        "name": "James",
        "email": "james@gmail.com",
        "userId": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Alicia",
        "email": "alicia@gmail.com",
        "userId": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It should be getting only the user named Alicia but it's getting all of them

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what's happening is that in your `GET_USER` you are specifying `type: GraphQLList(UserType)` as a return type, whereas you should be returning a single item: e.g. if you are sure it won't be null, a `GraphQLNonNull`.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the response, I try it but the response I got in the graphiql it's null, { "data": { "getUser": { "name": null, "email": null, "userId": null } } } It could be something else?